# Why WPF ProgressBar doesn't throw exception when its Value is greater than the Maximum?

Tags: wpf, progress-bar, outofrangeexception

I am new in `WPF` and I realized that the `ProgressBar` accepts values that is greater than the `Maximum` while I am working on a circular progressbar. Even it is set, the `Value` automatically equalized to the `Maximum`. So I don't want to work such a progressbar. I think this is not a safe way for a good programming. Because it makes you not to figure out when a progress is calculated wrong or anything else. I was in Winforms before the WPF and Winform progressbars have a behavior as I am talking about.

**I used this code and was expecting it to throw exception, but it did not.**

```
 ProgressBar prbar = new ProgressBar();
 prbar.Maximum = 100;
 prbar.Value = 10000;
```

How can I make it to throw exception when `Value` is over `Maximum` like in Winforms C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle ValueChanged event of progressbar and check if value is grether than maximum value then you can raise exception manually.